# Python - pythoncom.PumpMessages()

Tags: python, message-pump, pythoncom

I'm surprised to see that there is not a lot of explained documentation on the function `pythoncom.PumpMessages()`, or for the `pythoncom` module.

So what does `pythoncom.PumpMessages()` and `pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()`do and how? All I really know about it is used for catching events from input devices.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation on these methods can be found [here](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.4/pywin32/pythoncom.html).

The relevant bits are:

> - PumpWaitingMessages: Pumps all waiting messages for the current thread.
> - PumpMessages: Pumps all messages for the current thread until a WM_QUIT message.

Comment: This isn't super helpful. Not sure what a 'waiting message' is or a 'WM_QUIT'. Microsoft really needs to do better on documenting this. This website does better to provide examples of how to use this function & what it actually does: https://sourceforge.net/p/pyhook/wiki/PyHook_Tutorial/